# pywhatkit not sending message with pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-button

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import pywhatkit as kit
import csv

def open_csv_file():
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("CSV files", "*.csv")])
    if file_path:
        with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
            reader = csv.reader(file)
            for row in reader:
                numbers_listbox.insert(tk.END, row[0])  # Supponiamo che il numero di telefono sia nella prima colonna

def send_whatsapp_message():
    selected_numbers = numbers_listbox.curselection()
    message = message_entry.get()
    
    for index in selected_numbers:
        number = numbers_listbox.get(index)
        kit.sendwhatmsg(f'+{number}', message, 0, 0)  # Invia immediatamente
    
    
    # Ripulisci la casella di testo del messaggio
    message_entry.delete(0, tk.END)

def browse_file():
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    if file_path:
        attached_file_label.config(text=file_path)

# Creazione della finestra principale
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("AldiChat")

# Etichetta e casella di testo per il messaggio
message_label = tk.Label(root, text="Inserisci il messaggio:")
message_label.pack()
message_entry = tk.Entry(root, width=40)
message_entry.pack()

# Pulsante per aprire il file CSV
open_csv_button = tk.Button(root, text="Apri File Contatti", command=open_csv_file)
open_csv_button.pack()

# Elenco dei numeri di telefono dal file CSV
numbers_listbox = tk.Listbox(root, selectmode=tk.MULTIPLE)
numbers_listbox.pack()

# Pulsante per inviare il messaggio WhatsApp immediatamente
send_button = tk.Button(root, text="Invia Messaggi WhatsApp Immediatamente", command=send_whatsapp_message)
send_button.pack()

# Pulsante per allegare un file
attach_file_button = tk.Button(root, text="Allega File", command=browse_file)
attach_file_button.pack()

# Etichetta per visualizzare il percorso del file allegato
attached_file_label = tk.Label(root, text="")
attached_file_label.pack()

# Avvio dell'interfaccia grafica
root.mainloop()
```

This is my code. I think the problem is in the "send Whatsapp message" function:

```
def send_whatsapp_message():
    selected_numbers = numbers_listbox.curselection()
    message = message_entry.get()
    
    for index in selected_numbers:
        number = numbers_listbox.get(index)
        kit.sendwhatmsg(f'+{number}', message, 0, 0)  # Invia immediatamente
```

f' put "+" before the number -> 39XXXXXXXXXX -> +39XXXXXXXXXX

In console there isn't any type of error. I have tried writing directly the number and message but didn't work. (the numbers are stored in a csv file on my folder and it seems it works)

I have also tried this simple example i have found on internet and it works:

```
import pywhatkit


pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg("+39XXXXXXXXXX",
                    "Bene sono contento",
                    11, 40)
```

but even comparing them, I can't get the main code to work.

It could be a problem with the GUI?

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with tkinter. Do you have the same problem if you remove all of the tkinter code and directly call the pywhatkit API?

Comment: Ok, without tkinter woks!
Here is my code:
import pywhatkit as kit
import csv

def send_whatsapp_message():
    with open('test.csv', 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        for row in reader:
            number = row[0]
            message = input("Inserisci il messaggio da inviare a {}: ".format(number))
            kit.sendwhatmsg(f'+{number}', message, 17, 42)  # Invia immediatamente

send_whatsapp_message()

Also, i don't know how to send immediately the message.